# landing glider with chronic right drift or float

Tags: landing, glider

I just completed 30 glider flights with my instructor. Over the 2 weeks of training everything improved except for this tendency for the glider to move, drift or float to the right and always simultaneous to the flare.  Glider was a stick and I use my right hand on stick. Over 30 landings I always had the controls. Not once did plane drift to left... always right and regardless of calm or stable wind.    This was a bit sad because my instructor and I never fixed and I wasn't advanced to soloing because my landings weren't good enough. I was able to line up with runway fairly well upon turn to final and remain reasonably on target until rollout and flare.

Comment: One might specificly request a lesson to fix this.  You should still have control after flaring.  If the glider has a tendency to drift right (this may not be your fault) then ailerons left is the needed input.  Use rudder to keep nose straight.  Keep flying it all the way down to the ground.  My first few flares waited for the miracle of landing to happen.  Don't wait.  Keep control inputs active.

Comment: Hello David, welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com. What is your question? I see the problem you are having, but what do you expect from an answer?

Comment: Do you hold the stick with your right or your left hand? Could it be that you move it sideways to the right when pulling?

Comment: It is apparent that you are seeking advice, but there isn't actually a question in there.... Just a story. (sorry to nitpick, but this is a Q & A site - you gotta actually ask a question!)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have some kind of perception issue when you get close to the ground, where you are subconsciously banking slightly to the right to achieve what you perceive as wings level.

Keeping the nose aligned with the runway, it will result in a drift to the right in calm winds since you are basically sideslipping to the right without realizing it.

If this is what is happening, you will notice the yaw string pointing to the left as you drift right. That's about the only condition in calm winds that would create that kind of effect.

If you were pointing the nose to the right and holding wings level, and more or less flat-turning to the right, it would be a lot more obvious as the nose was pointed off-line from your track down the runway, and you'd get a bit of a sideways jolt as you touch down.

I would think that your instructor would pick up on this, but who knows, maybe the bank you are putting in is so subtle it's hard to tell from the back seat.

It could be as simple as tilting your head to the left without realizing it, and lowering the wing a degree or two to make your sight picture level.

Anyway, food for thought. If you do figure out what it is exactly you are doing to cause this, you will probably be able to fix the problem as you become aware.